# How to check the folder on the appearance in it of any new file?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

Help please. I can not find a solution. (Windows platform)
I need to:

1. Scan the folder
2. If you receive any new file.
3. Process the file.

Comment: Would you mind adding a little more info to your question? Do you want something constantly scanning or a single run event? Also what do you want to do to the new files?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Excuse me please. I need to scan a folder every n time.
If there were new files> run the utility.
I do not understand how to check on any new file. I only know how to check for a specific name.

Comment: For starters you could look into a scheduled task that runs every X minutes looking for files created less than X minutes ago with `Get-ChildItem` in PowerShell. You will not find anyone here that will just write the whole script for you. Showing some effort is usually required for requests.

Comment: Yes, i understand. I don`t want that someone would write script for me, I just want to find the way. Big thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to execute, this is all I can provide. You would theoretically run this as a scheduled task every 1 hour:

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "C:\TargetDirectory" | where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)})) {
    # Execute-Command -Target $file
}
```

Comment: simplified it a little

Answer (score 1):

Another method to detect "new files" is the archive attribute. Whenever a file is created or changed, this attribute is set by windows.

Whenever you process a file, unset it's archive attribute (`attrib -a file.ext`).

The advantage is, you don't depend on any timing.

To list "new" (or changed) files, use `dir /aa` (`dir /a-a` will list processed files)

for more infos see `dir /?` and `attrib /?`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`FileSystemWatcher` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to monitor the folder for new files.

It can easily be [used from PowerShell](http://blog.iisreset.me/2014/04/bigbrothershell-detect-and-suppress-those-files.html) as well:

```
$FSW = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
```

Then use `Register-ObjectEvent` to "listen" for events raised from it

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemWatcher is a utility I have recently learned and will definitely use in the future. The best part is that it relies on .net eventing, so you don't need to build an external triggering structure.

Here is an example of how I am using this in a 24/7 production environment (the full script receives an xml, processes it, and inserts the results into SQL in under 3 seconds).

```
    Function submit-resultFile {
#Actual file processing takes place here
    }

Function create-fsw {
    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier "Spectro FileCreated" -Action {
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $File = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Fullpath
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
        Write-Verbose "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green

        submit-ResultFile -xmlfile $file
        }
    }



# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                          
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $watchFolder, $watchFilter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $ResultsDirectory -Filter *.xml
foreach ($file in $xmlfiles)
{
submit-ResultFile -xmlfile $File.FullName
}


Create-fsw
 # Register a new File System Watcher
```

Several important points to be aware of:
- if files exist in that location before the FSW is created they WILL NOT trigger an "objectevent", so in my script you'll observe that I begin by running a sweep for existing files.

- when FSW does trigger you want it to process only 1 file at a time. Since the next file creation event will generate a new "objectevent". Structuring a FSW to work on multiple files per trigger will eventually result in a crash.